# Ruby how to delete arrays if they have matching element?

Tags: ruby

I have this array:

```
[[4, 50], [2, 28], [1, 4], [4, 41], [1, 9], [2, 25]]
```

I wish to construct an array consisting of those tuples [f,l] of this array such that there is no tuple [g,h] preceding [f,l] for which g==f. The selected tuples are to be in the same order as in the original array.

```
[[4, 50], [2, 28], [1, 4]]
```

Example if there are any more arrays that begin with 4 or 1 it should be deleted. It could be any integer, 4 and 1 is only an example.

Comment: group by first element and select only the first item of the group.

Comment: Why is `[2, 25]` deleted?

Comment: @sawa - Because there have already been a array starting with 2 ´[2, 28]´

Comment: in python I would do `c=set()` and `b = [c.add(x[0]) or x for x in a if x[0] not in c]`. don't know how that translates into ruby

Comment: @Railsbeginner But it does not start with 4 or 1.

Comment: @sawa - Only an exampe. It could be any integer.

Comment: @Railsbeginner Then, your description is highly misleading.

Comment: Does the order need to be preserved?

Comment: @sawa - yes the order is important

Comment: Rails, you've got two downvotes and two votes to close.  Let's rescue the question.  It's a good one and @Stefan provided a very good answer.  What you need to do is edit and insert something like the following, right before `"I want the result to be:"`: "I wish to construct an array consisting of those tuples `[f,l]` of this array such that there is no tuple `[g,h]` preceding `[f,l]` for which `g==f`.  The selected tuples are to be in the same order as in the original array." Yes, that's a bit of a mouthful, but I think it states unambiguously what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Haha, it worked. I came across this question after the edit and was thinking "why all the downvotes? this is a good question!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Array#uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq) seems to work:

```
[[4, 50], [2, 28], [1, 4], [4, 41], [1, 9], [2, 25]].uniq(&:first)
#=> [[4, 50], [2, 28], [1, 4]]
```

Comment: This is better than mine.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the documentation doesn't specify which duplicate is preserved and which is removed. The behavior could be implementation specific.

Comment: I expect that's a reflection on the incompleteness of the documentation, rather than evidence that maintenance of order was intentionally omitted from the spec.  It would make no sense for `uniq` with a parameter to return a value that is preceded in the array by a matching value.  Also, it is part of the spec (["yields items in order"](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/array/uniq_spec.rb)) for Ruby MRI.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the RubySpec pointer. The failing example would be ["compares elements based on the value returned from the block"](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/array/uniq_spec.rb#L83), returning `[1, 4]` instead of `[1, 2]` if the implementation would keep the last item

Answer (score 0):

I can't improve on @Stefan's answer, but here's another way that merely steps through the elements of the array:

```
a = [[4, 50], [2, 28], [1, 4], [4, 41], [1, 9], [2, 25]]

a.each_with_object([]) { |(f,l),a| a<<[f,l] unless a.any? { |g,_| g==f } }
  #=> [[4, 50], [2, 28], [1, 4]]
```